# Best book to study topological groups

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, topological-groups

I want to study the Topological groups and their applications..Which is the best book with a number of examples to study them from beginning.

I have been studying general topology from the the book $\textbf{Topology by Munkres}$.Also I am well-known with group theoretic concepts.What are the other core subjects that will be used in it?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I suggest you https://users.dimi.uniud.it/~dikran.dikranjan/ITG.pdf .

Answer (score 2):

I found the following references very useful:

1. Chapter 1 in the book "Transformation groups", by Tammo tom Dieck.
2. The book "Topology and Geometry", by Bredon.
3. For results stated in more generality: Topological groups, by Pontryagin.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of Geroge McCarty's *Topology:  An Introduction with Application to Topological Groups*.  It's a very fast--yet complete and readable--way to get the basics down.  It's also a Dover book, so likely under $10.

Comment: Sir, someone also suggested me the book 'Topological Groups
and Related Structures by  Alexander Arhangel’skii, Mikhail Tkachenko'.Can you say something about how is this book?Can I follow both the books together?@Randall